# FirebaseUI - using recaptcha with email sign-in method

Tags: javascript, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

**I want to add a captcha functionality to my FirebaseUI email-based login** to make it more difficult for bots and other abusers to log into my app.

I have investigated these:

1. This [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/firebaseui#phone_number) describes how to add a captcha to FirebaseUI when signing-in with a phone number but in my app I use the email signin method. I have tried doing the same for the email method:

   ```
   signInOptions: [
     {
        provider: authconst.EmailAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
        recaptchaParameters: {
          type: 'image', // 'audio'
          size: 'normal', // 'invisible' or 'compact'
          badge: 'bottomleft' //' bottomright' or 'inline' applies to invisible.
        },
      },
   ],
   ```

But this wont trigger the recaptcha. **How can I link the recaptcha to the email signing method?**

2. This [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/phone-auth#use-the-recaptcha-widget) describes how to add recatcha to an app, but I need to link it to the sign-in method otherwise a bot could just bypass the catcha and trigger the sign-in making the captcha useless. **How can I validate the captcha token response server-side? Are there some Cloud Function libraries to do that?**

Answer (score 1):

Recaptcha verification is only available in the Phone provider for Firebase Authentication. There is no way to configure it for the email+password provider, and FirebaseUI is not set up to include a recaptcha in the email+password flow either.

If you want to require the users to sign in with email+password **and** require them to solve a recaptcha, you'll have to build that yourself.

Comment: I have edited my question. This now answers point 1. If I build it myself, does Firebase provides some functionality to validate the recaptcha response token? This is my 2nd question now